# Error HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, apache, http, yql

[image: here is the snapshot of the code]

I am trying to use http request and response method but i am getting error that

> The import org.apache.commons cannot be resolved

i have included `httpcore.jar, httpclient.jar, httpmime.jar` but yet i am getting error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've imported versions 4.3+ of the libraries but are trying to use the old HTTP commons classes (version 3?), ie `GetMethod`.

The `HttpClient` is in package `org.apache.http.client`. The new version of `GetMethod` is `HttpGet`.

It's all [here](https://hc.apache.org/).

Answer (score -1):

You can download jar file from below link and import in your project

[Download jar File](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonshttpclientjar.htm)